# Which Facebook permissions allow for reading a user's posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If a user is to authorize an app to read their own posts, what Facebook permission does that app need? `read_stream` ?

According to Facebook docs, `read_stream` is not granted to normal apps, and only to Facebook-branded apps on platforms where Facebook is not available (tldr; no one will ever get this permission any more).

What is the alternative for normal Facebook apps? can we not read a user's wall anymore through apps? (I remember this was possible before)

Answer (score 1):

To get a users posts you can use user_status permission that is explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_status

Comment: which is now replaced by user_posts